# How to Block an IP range using .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, ip, block, vps

I want to block access of the following ips

https://gyazo.com/f41a53a1a385e41fe669064bff844a3a

i guess that comes in the range of

176.123.*.*

so will this work ?

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from 176.123.0.0/16
Allow from all
```

also i have to keep this htaccess outside public_html folder ?

Comment: People that have IPs in that range assigned can still access your site using a proxy server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the task

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from 176.123.0.0/16
Allow from all
```

and as Eric said the people within this ip rage can still access your site via a proxy server.

But if the allowed users have a particular ip range then this can sort it out

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
Allow from *ip range*
```

Comment: What is the /16 for?  Why the number 16?